# Why am I getting different version of Xcode from `pkgutil` and `xcodebuild`?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, xcodebuild

Getting the xcode version on my machine gets me two different results based on how I get it.

The first two entries get you `Xcode: 12.2.0.0.1.1603499215` and `Xcode 12.4`

```sh
## Xcode Versions
# Xcode from pkgutil --pkgs=com.apple.pkg.Xcode
-------------------------------------------------------
Xcode: 12.2.0.0.1.1603499215

-------------------------------------------------------
# xcodebuild -version
-------------------------------------------------------
Xcode 12.4
Build version 12D4e
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
# CLTools_Executables from pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
-------------------------------------------------------
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1612865496
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
CLTools_Executables: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815

-------------------------------------------------------
# Command Line Tools for Xcode with pkgutil
-------------------------------------------------------
CommandLineTools: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815

# xcrun --find xcodebuild
-------------------------------------------------------
/Volumes/SSD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
-------------------------------------------------------

# which xcodebuild && realpath xcodebuild
-------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/xcodebuild
/usr/bin/xcodebuild
-------------------------------------------------------

## GCC
# gcc -v
-------------------------------------------------------
Configured with: --prefix=/Volumes/SSD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Volumes/SSD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Volumes/SSD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
-------------------------------------------------------

# xcrun --find gcc
-------------------------------------------------------
/Volumes/SSD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
-------------------------------------------------------

# llvm-gcc -v
-------------------------------------------------------
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Volumes/SSD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
-------------------------------------------------------

## CLANG
# clang -v
-------------------------------------------------------
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Volumes/SSD/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Machine specs:

```sh
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.2
BuildVersion:   20D64
```

Comment: "Xcode" (IDE) and "Xcode command line tools" are different products (in most cases shipped together) they do not have to be aligned by version.

Comment: @MarekR thanks for helping out. I was not clear. I updated showing he different xcode versions output

Comment: "Xcode command line tools" can be installed without Xcode for example when machine plays a role of building agent (for example Jenkins slave). In such case IDE is not required.

Comment: Is it ok to have both Xcode and the command line tools installed? Regarding the original question, do you know why I would have to version of Xcode outputed? In fact, I have 3 version of xcode on this machine and none of them is 12.2

Comment: In fact you can have multiple version of each installed.